# R - Como criar uma variável atrasada (lag) condicionada ao individuo?

Tags: r, dplyr

Preciso atrasar uma variável da minha db (`dCoopCred`). Entretanto, ela não pode misturar o atraso de dois indivíduos (`CNPJ`). Gostaria que `LAG_Result_ant_desp` fosse `Result_ant_desp` em t-1 (período anterior).

Exemplo:

```
structure(list(CNPJ = c(5834, 5834, 5834, 5834, 5834, 9797, 9797, 
9797, 9797, 9797), ano = c(2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010), PIB = c(4, 6, 5, 1, 7, 4, 6, 5, 1, 7
), Result_ant_desp = c(5000, 7000, 6000, 2000, 3500, 1500, 2600, 
3000, 2100, 3100), LAG_Result_ant_desp = structure(c(9L, 6L, 
8L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("1500", "2000", "2100", 
"2600", "3000", "5000", "6000", "7000", "N/A"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Consegui atrasar um período usando o pacote `Hmisc` e o comando

```
dCoopCred$LAG_result_ant_desp <- Lag(dCoopCred$result_ant_desp, +1)
```

Entretanto, apenas esse comando acaba misturando `result_ant_desp` de diferentes anos e `CNPJ`.

Também estou usando o código

```
teste <- dCoopCred %>% 
  distinct(CNPJ, ano, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(CNPJ) %>% 
  mutate(LAG_result_ant_desp = lead(result_ant_desp, n = 1L)) %>% 
  select(-result_ant_desp) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  left_join(dCoopCred, ., by = c("ano", "CNPJ"))
```

Fez o que eu queria, mas esta gerando outro db, gostara que a variável fosse criada em dCoopCred

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Estou usando o seguinte código:

teste <- dCoopCred %>%
  distinct(CNPJ, ano, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(CNPJ) %>%
  mutate(LAG_result_ant_desp = lead(result_ant_desp, n = 1L)) %>%
  select(-result_ant_desp) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(dCoopCred, ., by = c("ano", "CNPJ")) 

Fez o que eu queria, mas esta gerando outro db, gostara que a variável fosse criada em dCoopCred.

Comment: Sobre o comentário anterior: onde tá "lead" é "lag"

Comment: @MarcusNunes editei, deu certo?

Comment: Se o código do segundo comentário está gerando o resultado desejado, porque tu não faz `dCoopCred  <- ...` em vez de `teste  <- ...` para evitar que outro objeto seja criado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há uma maneira mais simples de fazer o que a pergunta pede. Em vez de *pipes* `%>%`, usar `ave`.
Nota: a função `lag` que vai ser executada é a do pacote `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dCoopCred$LAG_Result_ant_desp <- with(dCoopCred, ave(Result_ant_desp, CNPJ, FUN = lag, -1))

dCoopCred
#   CNPJ  ano PIB Result_ant_desp LAG_Result_ant_desp
#1  5834 2006   4            5000                  NA
#2  5834 2007   6            7000                5000
#3  5834 2008   5            6000                7000
#4  5834 2009   1            2000                6000
#5  5834 2010   7            3500                2000
#6  9797 2006   4            1500                  NA
#7  9797 2007   6            2600                1500
#8  9797 2008   5            3000                2600
#9  9797 2009   1            2100                3000
#10 9797 2010   7            3100                2100
```

**Dados.**
Como os dados na pergunta já têm a nova coluna, aqui vai só com as primeiras quatro colunas, em formato `dput`.

```
dCoopCred <-
structure(list(CNPJ = c(5834, 5834, 5834, 5834, 5834, 9797, 9797, 
9797, 9797, 9797), ano = c(2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010), PIB = c(4, 6, 5, 1, 7, 4, 6, 5, 1, 7
), Result_ant_desp = c(5000, 7000, 6000, 2000, 3500, 1500, 2600, 
3000, 2100, 3100)), .Names = c("CNPJ", "ano", "PIB", "Result_ant_desp"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: nossa bem melhor ! Muito obrigado !